# ListView is alway null

Tags: android, android-layout

Hy!

My `ListView` is always null in my code. I don't have a plan why. The Error occurs in the setAdapter Method please help

Code:

```
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_sp);
    ArrayList<SPEntry> list = new ArrayList<SPEntry> ();
    EntryParse ep = new EntryParse(LVEntries.this, getIntent().getExtras().getString("JSON"));
    list = ep.getList();
    //list= new ArrayList<SPEntry>();
    Log.e("SP",String.valueOf(list.size()));
    ca = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.customlistitem, list);
    lv.setAdapter(ca);
    ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lv_sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" ></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Null, or empty? If it's null you should be getting a NullPointerException at lv.setAdapter

Comment: Did you forget to call setContentView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a call to `setContentView`. You must set the layout first, then retrieve views.

Comment: moreover, you may want to extend `ListActivity`, give your list and empty views the ids `android:id/list` and `android:id/empty`, and then set the adapter using `setListAdapter`.